# Azure Pipelines: Parallel tasks inside single job in pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Using Azure DevOps, I am creating a release pipeline in which I would like to have one stage having 1 job with 5 steps. First three steps are same task types but with different variables, and I would like to make them parallel so some flow would go like:

Job

*parallel:* step1, step2, step3

*then:* step4 (after all 3 parallel steps succeeded/failed)

*then:* step5 (after step4 is done)

**This is the current job setup**

[image: This is current job setup]

I am not sure how to set up **Control Options - run this task** for all of these steps. I would need somehow to set the first three to run immediately (maybe Custom condition "always()") and step 4 and step 5 to run sequentially after previous steps are done.

Step 5 can be: Even if the previous task has failed unless the deployment was cancelled, but I am not sure if I set the same setting for step 4 will it consider only step 3 as previous or all three previous (step1 - step3) tasks.

Also for **Execution plan Parallelism** I guess it's ok to set multi-agent to three since I would have max 3 steps executing in parallel overall.

[image: Job parallelism]

Answer (score 7):

> parallel: step1, step2, step3

If you have 5 tasks in one agent job, and just want to run the first three tasks parallel first, I'm afraid to say that this is not supported in Azure Devops.

When you put several tasks in one agent job, the tasks will and must run in order. Also, as you mentioned in the second pic, the specified **Multi-agent** is used for run agent jobs in parallel, rather than run tasks in parallel.

Fortunately, there has been such a suggestion raised by another user in our [official Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365659/ability-to-run-tasks-in-parallel.html). And there are many users with the same request as you. You can vote and comment there. Our Product Group team will take your suggestions kindly. If it has enough votes which means its high priority, the team will consider it seriously.

Comment: However this still (2 years later) is not provided!

Comment: I would love this. I am building an android app and I need apk and aab formats output. There seems to be no other way than to run two separate msbuild steps. I would like to run these in parallel

Comment: I think enough time and votes have elapsed to prove the last part of this answer wrong.

Comment: It's been 5 years since that suggestion was created and it's got plenty of votes... any progress?